# Redirects not working after adding dynamic to static code

Tags: .htaccess, dynamic, redirect, static

We are using for our ecommerce website ECT templates, and installed a code from a programmer that changed the dynamic url to static. However, we have some backlinks that we would like to redirect to the proper page (or we would settle for sending them all to one "all products" page that we have set-up.  The redirect we have currently returns a page that says "This product has been removed." Not good!

Here is the code that is on the htaccess file for the dynamic to static:

```
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*)$ /handle_url.php [L]
```

Here is the code in the handle_url.php file:

```
    <?php
  ob_start();
  session_start();
  include "vsadmin/db_conn_open.php";
  function sli_escape_string($estr){
    if(version_compare(phpversion(),'4.3.0')=='-1')        return(mysql_escape_string(trim($estr))); else return(mysql_real_escape_string(trim($estr)));
}
  $url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
   $url = trim($url, "/");
  $pos = strpos($url,'?');
  if ($pos > 0){
$url = substr($url,0,$pos);
  }
  $pos = strpos($url,".");

  if ($pos > 0){
$urlspec = substr($url, 0, $pos);
  } else {
  }

$store_url = $url;  

  $sSQL = "SELECT pID FROM products WHERE pURL='" . sli_escape_string($url) . "'";
  $query = mysql_query($sSQL);

  if ($query && mysql_num_rows($query)>0){
$rs = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
$_GET['prod']=$rs['pID'];
$explicitid=$rs['pID'];
include "proddetail.php";   
$plid = $explicitid;
  } else {
$sSQL = "SELECT sectionID, rootSection FROM sections WHERE     sectionURL='".sli_escape_string($url)."'";
  $query = mysql_query($sSQL);
if ($query && mysql_num_rows($query)>0){
    $rs = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
    $_GET['cat']=$rs['sectionID'];
    $explicitid=$rs['sectionID'];
    $secid = $explicitid;
    if ($rs['rootSection']==1){
        include "products.php";     
    } else {
        include "categories.php";
    }
} else {
    include "content.php";
}
  }  
  // For sections we want the .html
  ?>
```

And here is what I have unsuccessfully been trying to use to send the old dynamic link to the static page (there is no line break):

```
  redirect 301 /proddetail.php?prod=cooling-hydration-backpack-system http://www.veskimo.com/cooling-hydration-backpack-system.html
```

I so appreciate any help you can give me. I admit I am a bit out of my depth with this.
Thanks so much,
Janell

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following to the `.htaccess` file in the root directory of your site.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /proddetail\.php\?prod=cooling-hydration-backpack-system [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.veskimo.com/cooling-hydration-backpack-system.html [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thank you so very much!  That worked perfectly. you are so kind to help!  Cheers, Janell